# how to solve Deprecated API Usage WebViewi in React Native IOS?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-webview

I'm building a React Native application that I'm trying to deploy to the App Store.

I used a couple of packages, the ones that I think gives me the errors are

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal-datetime-picker/v/7.6.1

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-app-link

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-map-link

I found [this](https://medium.com/@ivanpagac_5657/how-to-solve-itms-90809-deprecated-api-usage-with-reactnative-0-60-in-ci-pipeline-132ca60dcf60) solution and I also deleted other files found in the same location with this name `RCTWKWebView` etc..

Now I get build error with missing files.

I also deleted those same files under pod config files../React/Core

What should I do ? Am I missing something?

It's the first time dealing with this error and I can't seem to find a useful solution.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your react-native versions cause the problem. You try to remove files include UIWebView in name on the XCode under the React folder. After that, you try to upload it to AppStore.

Comment: Actually I found some files that are importing the deleted files and now it's working fine and uploaded successfully